# Issue while having integration of Zoom SDK in android 12 operating system

Tags: android

Unable to create service com.zipow.videobox.share.ScreenShareServiceForSDK: and also Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.

It works on android 11 but it can't work on android 12.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not able to implement Zoom sdk integration in Android 12